# Scikit Pipeline Parameters - fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gamma'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

**Minimum viable example included ;)**

Want I want to to is simply to *use the parameters from GridSearchCV to use a Pipeline*.

```
#I want to create a SVM using a Pipeline, and validate the model (measure the accuracy)
#import libraries
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

#load test data
data = load_iris()
X_trainset, X_testset, y_trainset, y_testset = train_test_split(data['data'], data['target'], test_size=0.2)

#And here we prepare the pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('SVM', SVC())])
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid={'SVM__gamma':[0.1,0.01]}, cv=5)
grid.fit(X_trainset, y_trainset) 
# (Done! Now I can print the accuracy and other metrics)

#Now I want to put together training set and validation set, to train the model before deployment
#Of course, I want to use the best parameters found by GridSearchCV
big_x = np.concatenate([X_trainset,X_testset])
big_y = np.concatenate([y_trainset,y_testset])
```

Up to here, it works with no problem. Then, I write this line:

```
model2 = pipeline.fit(big_x,big_y, grid.best_params_)
```

Error!

```
TypeError: fit() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Then I tried to be more explicit:

```
model2 = pipeline.fit(big_x,big_y,fit_params=grid.best_params_)
```

Error again!

```
ValueError: Pipeline.fit does not accept the fit_params parameter. You can pass parameters to specific steps of your pipeline using the stepname__parameter format, e.g. `Pipeline.fit(X, y, logisticregression__sample_weight=sample_weight)`.
```

Then I tried (out of curiosity) to insert manually the parameter:

```
pipeline.fit(big_x,big_y, SVM__gamma= 0.01) #Note: I may need to insert many parameters, not just one
```

Error again :(

```
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gamma'
```

I cannot understand why it does not find gamma. I decided to print pipeline.get_params() to have an idea.

```
In [11]: print(pipeline.get_params())
Out [11]: 
{'memory': None, 
 'steps': [('scaler', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)), ('SVM', SVC(C=1.0, break_ties=False, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
tol=0.001, verbose=False))], 
 'verbose': False, 
 'scaler': StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True), 
 'SVM': SVC(C=1.0, break_ties=False, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False), 
'scaler__copy': True, 'scaler__with_mean': True, 'scaler__with_std': True, 'SVM__C': 1.0, 'SVM__break_ties': False, 'SVM__cache_size': 200, 'SVM__class_weight': None, 'SVM__coef0': 0.0, 'SVM__decision_function_shape': 'ovr', 'SVM__degree': 3, 'SVM__gamma': 'scale', 'SVM__kernel': 'rbf', 'SVM__max_iter': -1, 'SVM__probability': False, 'SVM__random_state': None, 'SVM__shrinking': True, 'SVM__tol': 0.001, 'SVM__verbose': False}
```

I can find SVM__gamma in the list! So why is there an error?

Version of Scikit: 0.22.1

Version of python: 3.7.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.fit()`, as in, the call to the `.fit()` function of the SVC Class, [has no parameter called gamma](https://scikit-learn.org/0.22/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit). When you call `pipeline.fit(SVM__gamma)` it's passing the gamma param to the `.fit()` call of the SVM step, which isn't going to work.

You set params in scikit-learn using the [.set_params()](https://scikit-learn.org/0.22/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.set_params) functions. At the lowest level (I.E. against SVC itself) you can just do `SVC.set_params(gamma='blah')`. In the pipeline you'd follow the same double underscore notation you're using in the param grid, so `pipeline.set_params(SVM__gamma=blah)`,

If you're only setting a single param against a single step of your pipeline, it's usually convenient to access the step directly with `pipeline.named_steps.SVM.set_params(gamma='blah')` , or else use `pipeline.set_params(**grid.best_params_)` to use your grid search's best params. (the ** notation explodes a dict of {'A':1, 'B':2} out into A=1, B=2 for you)

Here's a snippet of a script that does what I think you're trying to do (albeit with different algorithms):

```
# Set the classifier as an XGBClassifier

clf_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
        ('classifier', XGBClassifier(n_jobs=6, n_estimators=20))
    ]
)


# In[41]:

# Cross validation: 60 iterations with 3 fold CV.

n_features_after_transform = clf_pipeline.named_steps.preprocessor.fit_transform(df).shape[1]

param_grid = {
    'classifier__max_depth':stats.randint(low=2, high=100),
    'classifier__max_features':stats.randint(low=2, high=n_features_after_transform),
    'classifier__gamma':stats.uniform.rvs(0, 0.25, size=10000),
    'classifier__subsample':stats.uniform.rvs(0.5, 0.5, size=10000),
    'classifier__reg_alpha':stats.uniform.rvs(0.5, 1., size=10000),
    'classifier__reg_lambda':stats.uniform.rvs(0.5, 1., size=10000)
}

rscv = RandomizedSearchCV(
    clf_pipeline,
    param_grid,
    n_iter=60,
    scoring='roc_auc',
    cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)

)

rscv.fit(df, y)


# In[42]:


# Set the tuned best params and beef up the number of estimators.

clf_pipeline.set_params(**rscv.best_params_)
clf_pipeline.named_steps.classifier.set_params(n_estimators=200)
```

So long story short, you can set an individual parameter by accessing the class you want to set the param for in the pipeline's `named_steps`. To set the parameters that your Grid Search identified as best, use `pipeline.set_params(**grid.best_params_)`